# Visa requirements for Dubai airport

Tags: visas

Good afternoon, I'm flying to New Zealand next year and have a 17 hour layover in Dubai, do I need a visa to leave the airport?

Comment: What is your passport? see here: https://www.mofa.gov.ae/EN/ConsularServices/Pages/Visa-Information.aspx

Comment: Yes you need, requirements may differ based on your passport.

Answer (score 2):

Except for GCC citizens, everyone needs a visa to enter the UAE.

The difference is if you can get the visa on arrival or do you have to apply for it in advance - and that depends on your nationality.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your nationality.
I flew to NZ with a layover in Dubai, so same as you, and I didn't need any visa, my italian passport was enough.
I left the airport with no problem.

(not true that "Except for GCC citizens, everyone needs a visa to enter the UAE.")

Comment: The visa you need is free of charge and is stamped at the immigration. You need a visa, it is just that you don't need to apply for it in advance. This also means that you may not be allowed entry (ie, you are not guaranteed entry at all).

Comment: if by "Visa" you mean a stamp so, yes, you need a visa.

Comment: _"If your country of nationality appears on the list below, no advance visa arrangements are required to visit the UAE. Simply disembark your flight at Dubai International Airport and proceed to Immigration, where your passport will be stamped with a 30-days visit visa free of charge."_ [source](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/uae-visas/)

Comment: I think that the question was related to the need of applying for a visa BEFORE the travel. Of course you need a stamp to leave the airport..

Comment: You don't need a stamp to leave the airport - you only need one if you need a visa. You are confusing stamps with visas. US citizens need a visa, but don't get stamped since they can use the e-gate.

Answer (score 0):

You might need visa depending on your nationality. Find out [here](https://www.mofa.gov.ae/EN/ConsularServices/Pages/Visa-Information.aspx). If you are travelling with Emirates Airlines, they will provide free transit visa, accommodation and ground transfer for all transits above 8 hours, provided you apply through 'manage booking' at least 24 hours before you fly.